# Node JS deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I tried to put my Node JS app for my student project.

Here is the project :

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tJPP.png)

N.B: Public is the result of an "npm run build from the front made with Vue JS"

When i work locally, I use a specif path to call request from my back.
Example : "http://localhost:3000/read/chosenemployee/"

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DwHE.png)

But when I put my project online, I use the command "npm start" and use a different port (for example 3535) and replace the "http://localhost:3000" by "https://localhost:3535" and I have this error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I also tried :

- "http://localhost:3535"
- "https://myDomaineName:3535"

But nothing change.

Here is my app.js :

```
//1- CREATION DES DEPENDANCES DE MODULES
//MODULE DE JS.NODE
// const https = require('https');
// const fs = require('fs');
// var http = require("http");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//Paramétrage du CORS afin qu'il n'y ai pas de blocage
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysqlApostrophe = require("mysql-apostrophe");
//Module permettant de faire des refresh en SPA
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

//IMPORT DES MODULES CREES
var dataBase = require('./routes/dataBase');

//ATTENTION SEMBLE POSER PROBLEME A NODE EN LOCAL
app.use(history()); 
app.use(cors());
//2- MISE EN PLACE DU BODY PARSER QUI PERMET DE LIRE LES JSON ET URL ENVOYE PAR LE FORMULAIRE
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // LIRE LES BODY ENCODES EN JSON
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ // LIRE LES BODY ENCODES EN URL
    extended: true
}));

//Mise en place de express
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))

//3- MISE EN PLACE DE mysqlApostrophe
app.use(mysqlApostrophe); //PERMET D'INSERER DES CHAMPS CONTENANT DES APOSTROPHES


//4- RECUPERATION DES FICHIERS ROUTES DANS LE DOSSIER ROUTES
const creation = require("./routes/create");
const lecture = require("./routes/read");
const maj = require("./routes/update");
const suppression = require("./routes/delete")

//5- UTILISATION DES ROUTES
app.use("/create", creation);
app.use("/read", lecture);
app.use("/update", maj);
app.use("/delete", suppression)

//Gestion de la mise en production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    //Static folder
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/')).use
    //Handle SPA
    app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
} else {
    //Static folder
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/')).use
    //Handle SPA
    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
}

//4- CHOIX DU PORT UTILISE PAR LE SERVEUR
const port = process.env.PORT || 8898; //RECUPERE UN PORT LIBRE SINON 3000
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Le serveur utilise le port : " + port)
});
```

And here is my .htaccess put at the root of my public_html folder :

```
#1. Forcing HTTPS connection:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#2. Removing port from URL:
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
DirectoryIndex

# Add headers to all responses.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Simple URL redirect:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8898/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

And the online folder :

[Online folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kjld.png)

Comment: A question about "when I put my project online": _where and how_?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your answer. I put my website on fastcomet.com using the c-panel and even using just the public_html forlder it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried following the steps provided by the cPanel documentation?
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application

Comment: perhaps i'm wrong, but doesn't this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8898/$1 [P]` literally rewrite all requests to localhost:8898? there's no way you'll ever connect remotely with it enabled

Comment: It does. @Yassuke remember to look at your dev tools, notably the "console" and "network" tabs, because that's where you'll see both errors _and_ the network requests that are actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to check on the port where you host your application.  Typically non standard port are closed off, try serving on standard port like 80, 443.  So outside requests are block off.  If you can test your request locally on where you host your app, then that will rule out that outside world can't reach your app (ssh or remote into the server where you're hosting and run something like curl localhost:3535).

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately It doesn't work.I don't understand why. Maybe I forget something but I don't know what.

Comment: I agree with noobius, it looks like a port problem. What does the console.log outputs on remote server? What is the process.env.PORT on the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

The host in the address `http://localhost:3535` is `localhost`. This always refers to your local machine.

When you start your project on another computer and want to access it from your machine, you will have to enter that computer's address. If you know its IP address, you can replace `localhost` with it, e.g. `http://151.101.129.69:3535`. (This example IP address is stackoverflow's IP)

If the machine has a readable host name associated, you can us that name, e.g. `http://www.example.org:3535`.

The examples assume that your application starts up correctly and is not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: thank You for your answer. I tried to follow your advice but it doesn't work.

Comment: a naked "it doesn't work" shuts down this entire avenue of solution, which is no good because it *is* the correct answer - what specifically doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

In this part of your code

```
app.listen(port, function () {
console.log("Le serveur utilise le port : " + port)
});
```

Try to modify like this:

```
app.listen(port,HOST, function () { // port, your hostString, and callback
console.log("Le serveur utilise le port : " + port)
});
```

Sometimes that is the problem.

If you want https in your server this is how you need to do it:

```
//your other code stuff
const https = require('https'); 
const options = {}// your credentials options
const server = https.createServer(options,app);


server.listen(port,HOST, function () { // port, your hostString, and callback
console.log("Le serveur utilise le port : " + port)
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

> const port = process.env.PORT || 8898; //RECUPERE UN PORT LIBRE SINON
>   3000

This is most likely the issue, remove 'process.env.PORT ||' and try port 8898 again